# Upload video to picasaweb, get a list or link from Rss?

Tags: video, rss, picasa

I'm doing my practise on creating a movies site. I upload my video to picasaweb, and using rss to get link rendered (m=22,m=18...)

To avoid wasting time, i want a php code which help me to get all of the link i want from album picasaweb.
For example my album link is: `https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/108709628273613466583/albumid/6288011687853610609?alt=rss&kind=photo&authkey=Gv1sRgCJ-G_PbBw5m6NA&hl=en_US`

I want a php code which directlt show me the name of the movie + link 22.
For example with the link above, the result would be:

```
1.
cyberbully.2011.720p.hdtv.x264-sys.mkv
QPTRzhjYSSP9mbV3daLAsuy82q9AFdyfCdiWrkOxIPnuESkShye8lP0lyMfvN7vFbe7rzKRkwWM=m22
2.
Allies.2014.720p.WEB-DL.x264.AC3-EVO.mkv
23j7Nt3h_DS7-IjdQHOHAVLMSN7pH4QAPQ7xmAkN_TYIY_Wez-kf-ayDk4psuRRzFnvqSK4Xcsk=m22
3.
Moms.Night.Out.2014.720p.WEB-DL.x264.AC3-EVO.mkv
17dXa3_3z8wU6vaYaqCiAKAGMTVk6UtDf9J-RpbgHcUj50ig1L_I_8MucypmlCYIDSyCVWZ0gOI=m22
```

Moreover, in case the 22-link is not ready yet(For example the 1 st movie), the result will show:

```
1.cyberbully.2011.720p.hdtv.x264-sys.mkv
22 is not realdy    

2.
    Allies.2014.720p.WEB-DL.x264.AC3-EVO.mkv
    23j7Nt3h_DS7-IjdQHOHAVLMSN7pH4QAPQ7xmAkN_TYIY_Wez-kf-ayDk4psuRRzFnvqSK4Xcsk=m22

3.
    Moms.Night.Out.2014.720p.WEB-DL.x264.AC3-EVO.mkv
    17dXa3_3z8wU6vaYaqCiAKAGMTVk6UtDf9J-RpbgHcUj50ig1L_I_8MucypmlCYIDSyCVWZ0gOI=m22
```

Please help me, i'm stuck with this for many weeks...
Thank you a lot

And plz write down the whole code for me, cuz i'm just a beginer...

Answer (score 0):

http://ankudowicz.com/picasa-links-extractor/index.php

I find a website which is suitable for my need, someone please get me the code :(